# Nested resources for recursive association in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord, entity-relationship

In my application a user can rate another user.
I defined the following schema:

```
# feedback.rb
class Feedback < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :subject, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'subject_id'
  belongs_to :writer, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'writer_id'
end

# user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :feedbacks, class_name: 'Feedback', foreign_key: 'subject_id'
   has_many :written_feedback, class_name: 'Feedback', foreign_key: 'writer_id'
end
```

Right now I have to define the routes and I'm stuck thinking about nesting or not the resources and if yes how.

This is how I tried to define the routes but I'm not sure about that.
This way I can only reach or the feedbacks given to an user or the feedbacks written from an user.

```
#routes
....
  resources :users, except: [:new, :edit] do 
    resources :feedbacks, except: [:new, :edit]
  end
```

Is this the best way to build this schema?

Answer (score 0):

After some attempts I decided to extends the feedbacks_controller.

```
class FeedbacksController < ApplicationController
end

module Feedbacks
  class ReceivedFeedbacksController < FeedbacksController
  end
end


module Feedbacks
  class GivenFeedbacksController < FeedbacksController
  end
end


#routes
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    resources :given_feedbaks,
              only: [:index],
              controller: 'feedbacks/given_feedbacks'
    resources :received_feedbaks,
              only: [:index],
              controller: 'feedbacks/received_feedbaks'
  end
  resources :feedbacks, only: [:show, :create, :update, :destroy]
end
```